# Does Raspberry PI 4 support Secure boot

Tags: boot, security

Just wanted to know if Raspberry PI 4 supports secure boot ?

Thanks,
Swapnil

Answer (score 0):

There are some Secure Boot Solutions for Rasberry Pi that allow encryption and access protection of data stored on the microSD card by various configurable security policies.